# Jclouds example not working on host machine (devstack)

Tags: api, jclouds, keystone

I installed Devstack on Virtualbox and I want to use Jclouds for application development on my host machine, when I test the homepage example

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;
import com.google.common.io.Closeables;
import com.google.inject.Module;
import org.jclouds.ContextBuilder;
import org.jclouds.logging.slf4j.config.SLF4JLoggingModule;
import org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.NovaApi;
import org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.domain.Server;
import org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.features.ServerApi;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

public class JCloudsNova implements Closeable {
private final NovaApi novaApi;
private final Set<String> regions;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JCloudsNova jcloudsNova = new JCloudsNova();

    try {
        jcloudsNova.listServers();
        jcloudsNova.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        jcloudsNova.close();
    }
}

public JCloudsNova() {
    Iterable<Module> modules = ImmutableSet.<Module>of(new     SLF4JLoggingModule());

    String provider = "openstack-nova";
    String identity = "demo:demo"; // tenantName:userName
    String credential = "nova";

    novaApi = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(provider)
            .endpoint("http://127.0.0.0:5000/v2.0/")
            .credentials(identity, credential)
            .modules(modules)
            .buildApi(NovaApi.class);
    regions = novaApi.getConfiguredRegions();
}

private void listServers() {
    for (String region : regions) {
        ServerApi serverApi = novaApi.getServerApi(region);

        System.out.println("Servers in " + region);

        for (Server server : serverApi.listInDetail().concat()) {
            System.out.println("  " + server);
        }
    }
}

public void close() throws IOException {
    Closeables.close(novaApi, true);
}
}
```

I get this output :

```
[main] DEBUG o.j.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod - >> invoking   AuthenticationApi.authenticateWithTenantNameAndCredentials
[main] DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Sending request 731849735: POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0/tokens HTTP/1.1
[main] DEBUG jclouds.wire - >> "Sensitive data in payload, use PROPERTY_LOGGER_WIRE_LOG_SENSITIVE_INFO override to enable logging this data."
[main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0/tokens HTTP/1.1
[main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> Accept: application/json
[main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> Content-Type: application/json
[main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> Content-Length: 92
[main] DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Receiving  response 731849735: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
[main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
[main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Connection: Keep-Alive
[main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - << x-openstack-request-id: req-ee75199f-27ba-4d95-bc68-b5ddbd38235e
[main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Vary: X-Auth-Token
[main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Date: Sun, 01 Nov 2015 11:15:11 GMT
[main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Content-Type: application/json
[main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - << Content-Length: 5187
[main] DEBUG jclouds.wire - << "{"access": {"token": {"issued_at": "2015-11-01T11:15:11.741173", "expires": "2015-11-01T12:15:11Z", "id": "a907229e8fa94560a3d87ffd8bc959e7", "tenant": {"description": null, "enabled": true, "id": "b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a", "name": "admin"}, "audit_ids": ["SWSlpB88SK6JFcfuAjqi_g"]}, "serviceCatalog": [{"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a", "id": "083ebebf2f284add866b15092e4b4918", "publicURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "compute", "name": "nova"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2.1/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2.1/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a", "id": "4fd099ac1b0542a8994281d86fc50e19", "publicURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2.1/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "computev21", "name": "novav21"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8776/v2/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8776/v2/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a", "id": "0b0499b8a437401bb96968d9f76ca7c7", "publicURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8776/v2/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "volumev2", "name": "cinderv2"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8779/v1.0/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8779/v1.0/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a", "id": "9dc6091b06e545bdaee41945d54a45ad", "publicURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8779/v1.0/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "database", "name": "trove"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://10.0.2.15:9292", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://10.0.2.15:9292", "id": "1c23e7d2ad234adaa9e8109472c28ac2", "publicURL": "http://10.0.2.15:9292"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "image", "name": "glance"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8386/v1.1/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8386/v1.1/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a", "id": "2d3d2a5dff9b4799bc16e66409c66479", "publicURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8386/v1.1/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "data_processing", "name": "sahara"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8000/v1", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8000/v1", "id": "0c9fa4ded5b14bb780a73f843baec0be", "publicURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8000/v1"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "cloudformation", "name": "heat-cfn"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8776/v1/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8776/v1/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a", "id": "17f424ba438940b281c91287a8e2f247", "publicURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8776/v1/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "volume", "name": "cinder"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8773/", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8773/", "id": "930d840f89eb4b978a1b6aa4c43550d6", "publicURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8773/"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "ec2", "name": "ec2"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8004/v1/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8004/v1/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a", "id": "59524478bb014029832a84bbe55e7600", "publicURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8004/v1/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "orchestration", "name": "heat"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8080", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8080/v1/AUTH_b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a", "id": "5f4a0e402b0041a799207dc70f6abb01", "publicURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8080/v1/AUTH_b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "object-store", "name": "swift"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8386/v1.1/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8386/v1.1/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a", "id": "0d0183f6f94048bba68bbc540375debd", "publicURL": "http://10.0.2.15:8386/v1.1/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "data-processing", "name": "sahara"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://10.0.2.15:35357/v2.0", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://10.0.2.15:5000/v2.0", "id": "249b7361cf944d5b999666d3c89dff63", "publicURL": "http://10.0.2.15:5000/v2.0"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "identity", "name": "keystone"}, {"endpoints": [{"adminURL": "http://10.0.2.15:9696/", "region": "RegionOne", "internalURL": "http://10.0.2.15:9696/", "id": "59f12fcbf8044e688dd184914f1d4337", "publicURL": "http://10.0.2.15:9696/"}], "endpoints_links": [], "type": "network", "name": "neutron"}], "user": {"username": "admin", "roles_links": [], "id": "c2430e83e4814f058e7bf7ac783b04ec", "roles": [{"name": "admin"}], "name": "admin"}, "metadata": {"is_admin": 0, "roles": ["2d225038f03f4d1d928994c77728fbb6"]}}}"
[main] DEBUG o.j.o.k.v.s.RegionIdToURIFromAccessForTypeAndVersion - endpoints for apiType compute and version 2: {RegionOne=[Endpoint{id=083ebebf2f284add866b15092e4b4918, region=RegionOne, publicURL=http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a, internalURL=http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a, adminURL=http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a}]}
[main] DEBUG o.j.l.s.f.RegionIdsFromConfiguration - no jclouds.regions configured for provider openstack-nova
Servers in RegionOne
[main] DEBUG o.j.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod - >> invoking server:list
[main] DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Sending request -1892986886: GET http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a/servers/detail HTTP/1.1
[main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> GET http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a/servers/detail HTTP/1.1
[main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> Accept: application/json
[main] DEBUG jclouds.headers - >> X-Auth-Token: a907229e8fa94560a3d87ffd8bc959e7
[main] DEBUG o.j.h.h.BackoffLimitedRetryHandler - Retry 1/5: delaying for 54 ms: server error: [method=org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.features.ServerApi.public abstract org.jclouds.collect.PagedIterable org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.features.ServerApi.listInDetail()[], request=GET http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a/servers/detail HTTP/1.1]
[main] DEBUG o.j.h.i.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService - Sending request -1892986886: GET http://10.0.2.15:8774/v2/b37cfd133b05457d82adc239cb762a6a/servers/detail HTTP/1.1
```

Notes that I use intelijIdea for an IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably related to the network configuration of the virtualbox.
Your first request is going to 127.0.0.1:5000, and is handled correctly by the Openstack Keystone service.

The keystone response includes the address of the nova service endpoint - 10.0.2.15:8774 - which is where your API call to list the servers should go. Your client seems to be unable to connect to this IP.

Check your virtualbox network configuration - make sure that the network mode allows the host operating system to connect to the guest operating system.

Comment: which network mode you mean ? I set SSH port and Horizon GUI port

Comment: Your openstack instance is running on an IP of 10.0.2.15. The horizon web console is probably also running on that port. Whatever you did to let the GUI port (80) redirect to the VM' port 80, you need to do the same for port 8774, and any other port that the openstack services expose and you need.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox cannot pass virtualization extensions. Your devstack most likely cannot boot VMs under virtualbox.